# Creating executable on visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, clr, executable

I have written a program on c++ and i want to create an exe file so I can run it on other computers.

I'm getting this error message:

> cl : Command line error D8016: '/clr:pure' and '/MTd' command-line options are incompatible

What should  do?

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: Don't use `clr:pure` and `MTd` at the same time? In other words, you need to figure out what settings you have altered, and then set the appropriate option to not use those conflicting options.

Comment: thanks. What are clr:pure, MTd and how do I set those options? @MatsPetersson

Comment: @ SLaks I didn't understand the question. I run "build" if that's what you meant